# Android App crashing at beginning

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, program-entry-point

I'm learning Android development and I'm wondering why is my app crashing

Main code:

```
package com.tester.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class Main extends Activity {

    Button carrega;
    TextView texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        carrega = (Button)findViewById(R.id.carregar);
        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        carrega.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                texto.setText("newtext");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And my XML is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#A5BB76"
        android:text="@string/message" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/carregar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/OK"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this app works OK just by the XML, but if I define those variables (Button and TextView) it crashes at start. Why is this happening? How can I solve this? If I take off my Java new code (and maintain the default) the app works, but it doesn't whenever I declare one of those variables.

I appreciate your time. Thank you very much. Any help would be great.

Comment: move `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line before initializing Button and TextView

Answer (score 4):

You should Initialise the View after the  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Change It

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        carrega = (Button)findViewById(R.id.carregar);
        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

To

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        carrega = (Button)findViewById(R.id.carregar);
        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But on the tutorials I'm following the instructor does the code like that, so why does it need to be different? Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: ops! that was my fault. I rectified the code and you are completely right. Thats a mistake I'm not making again.  Thank you!